# Is it possible to use Julia's Pkg.submit under windows?

Tags: git, julia

Julia's built-in package handling is very handy, and I would like to use it to contribute code.  However, I haven't been able to get Pkg.submit working on a windows machine.  Has anyone been able to do this, and if so, how did you do it?

The issue seems to be getting an ssh-agent running when git is called from julia.  I've tried to make it run automatically by doing [this](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/) to Julia's copy of .profile but haven't been able to get it working.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is a known issue being tracked at [JuliaLang/PkgDev.jl#26](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PkgDev.jl/issues/26).